# Combining different ngModules similar to jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, angular-module

Is there any way/place where I can combine all my ngModules and include them using single js file(something similar to jqueryUI). Of course I can combine them using tools like YUI, but for my requirement is there any functionality that does the same task.

Answer (score 0):

NPM can do this with the help of browserify

A few sites I have just bookmarked as I will be implementing a new angular-based application for mobile and web:

http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-browserify/

http://browserify.org/

http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

If you want to learn a tool for pulling this together using gulp, see also:

http://www.100percentjs.com/just-like-grunt-gulp-browserify-now/

Finally, a good example of combining javascript files (used in testing) into a production single file:

https://webdevstudios.com/2015/03/18/using-browserify-with-javascript/